# How to cascade delete from parent using alembic?

Tags: python, postgresql, alembic

Maybe I'm missing something here that is super simple, but I have a postgresql db that has several tables structured as such:

```
- releases
 |- releases_contributions
 |- releases_primary contributions
 |- recording
   |- recording_contributions
   |- recording_primary_contributions
```

where `releases_contributions`, `releases_primary_contributions` & `recording` all have a column that has a ForeignKey associated with the auto generated `releases_id`.

I've made a revision to update the `ondelete` parameter:

```
    op.alter_column('recording', 'releases_id', sa.ForeignKey('releases.releases_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    op.alter_column('recording_contributions', 'recording_fk_id', sa.ForeignKey('recording.recording_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    op.alter_column('recording_primary_contributions', 'recording_fk_id', sa.ForeignKey('recording.recording_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    op.alter_column('releases_contributions', 'releases_fk_id', sa.ForeignKey('releases.releases_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    op.alter_column('releases_primary_contributions', 'releases_fk_id', sa.ForeignKey('releases.releases_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

And in my initial alembic upgrade I have this, of course:

```
op.add_column('releases', 'releases_id', primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
```

I'm trying to delete a row in `releases`

```
delete from releases where releases_id=1;
```

that then cascades down to the other tables and deletes any row that has that release as it's foreign key.

But whenever I run that command, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  update or delete on table "releases" violates foreign key constraint "releases_contributions_releases_fk_id_fkey" on table "releases_contributions"
DETAIL:  Key (releases_id)=(1) is still referenced from table "releases_contributions".
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you may need to do `op.drop_constraint` and  `op.create_foreign_key` in your alembic revision in order to properly update the foreign key constraint with on delete cascade property.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was not the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the alembic revision with the downgrades/upgrades below, then running `alembic downgrade -1` and `alembic upgrade head` fixed this issue.

```
def upgrade():
    op.alter_column('recording', 'releases_id', sa.ForeignKey('releases.releases_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    op.alter_column('recording_contributions', 'recording_fk_id', sa.ForeignKey('recording.recording_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    op.alter_column('recording_primary_contributions', 'recording_fk_id', sa.ForeignKey('recording.recording_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    op.alter_column('releases_contributions', 'releases_fk_id', sa.ForeignKey('releases.releases_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    op.alter_column('releases_primary_contributions', 'releases_fk_id', sa.ForeignKey('releases.releases_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))


def downgrade():
    op.drop_contraint('releases_id', 'releases')
    op.drop_contraint('releases_id', 'recording')
    op.drop_contraint('releases_fk_id', 'releases_contributions')
    op.drop_contraint('releases_fk_id', 'releases_primary_contributions')
    op.drop_contraint('recording_fk_id', 'recording_contributions')
    op.drop_contraint('recording_fk_id', 'recording_primary_contributions')
```